# Ping Pong paddles are not acting as expected

Tags: c++, sfml

I am trying to learn SFML and C++ so I decided to try and make my own Ping Pong game however for some reason player 1 is not clearing properly and player 2 is a lot slower and jittery (same as player 1).

Could someone help me out with this please?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "ResourcePath.hpp"

#include <iostream>

class Paddel {
    int speed = 3;
    sf::Vector2f border;
    sf::Vector2f size;
    sf::Vector2f position;
    sf::Vector2f screenSize;
public:
    sf::RectangleShape shape;

    Paddel(sf::Vector2f screenSize,int player)
    {
        this->screenSize = screenSize;
        this->size = sf::Vector2f(20,100);
        this->border = sf::Vector2f(8,6);

        if(player == 1)
            this->position = border;
        else if(player == 2) {
            position.x = (screenSize.x - size.x) - border.x;
            position.y = border.y;
        }

        this->shape.setSize(this->size);
        this->shape.setPosition(this->position);
    }

    void moveUp()
    {
        this->position.y -= this->speed;
        if(this->position.y < this->border.y)
            this->position.y += this->speed;
        this->shape.setPosition(this->position);
    }

    void moveDown()
    {
        this->position.y += this->speed;
        //100 - (600 + 5)
        if(this->position.y > (this->screenSize.y - this->border.y) - this->size.y)
            this->position.y -= this->speed;
        this->shape.setPosition(this->position);
    }
};

using std::cout;
using std::endl;


int main()
{
    sf::Vector2f screenSize(800,600);
    sf::RenderWindow Window(sf::VideoMode(screenSize.x,screenSize.y),"Ping Pong");
    Window.setFramerateLimit(60);
    Window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    Paddel playerOne(screenSize,1);
    Paddel playerTwo(screenSize,2);

    const sf::Time TimePerFrame = sf::seconds(1.f/60.f);
    sf::Clock clock;
    sf::Time timeSinceLastUpdate = sf::Time::Zero;
    sf::Time elapsedTime;

    bool play = true;

    while(Window.isOpen())
    {
        Window.clear();
        sf::Event Event;

        while(Window.pollEvent(Event))
        {
            if(Event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                Window.close();
        }

        elapsedTime = clock.restart();
        timeSinceLastUpdate += elapsedTime;
        if(play){
            if(timeSinceLastUpdate > TimePerFrame){
                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::W))
                {
                    playerOne.moveUp();
                }
                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::S))
                {
                    playerOne.moveDown();
                }

                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
                {
                    playerTwo.moveUp();
                }
                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
                {
                    playerTwo.moveDown();
                }

                if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::P))
                    play = false;
            }

            Window.draw(playerOne.shape);
            Window.draw(playerTwo.shape);

            Window.display();
        }
    }
}
```

Also if my code is messy that is because I am trying to make it my self with little knowledge of C++ and SFML.

Comment: Perhaps better suited over @ http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or do you have a specific question? PS. A good debugger is the developers best friend...

Comment: This question sounds like it is asking about specific issues with the code, and therefore would not be a good fit for Code Review until the code works as intended.

Comment: So should I move it or not?

Comment: hang around here a bit more and see if you get some answers but generally  it is easier to get good answers if you show some efforts trying to debug you code yourself, i.e. Add print statements etc. and then ask about something more specific then "it doesn't work".

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Adding debugging info now.

Comment: Do not move this question to Code Review.  It will get close as off-topic because the code does not work as expected.

Comment: Ok. Sorry. I have deleted it off of CR.

Comment: @FredrikPihl [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was all the action was happening inside the `Window.pollEvent(Event)` loop. To fix the issue I took it out of there. Have no idea what it was doing in there. Hate typos!